# Is there a method that can be used when a template has been fully rendered in Angular2?

Tags: angular

I am playing with Angular2 and am trying to do the following:

- Show a list of items
- When the items have finished loading in the DOM, make a call to an external library to format the items a certain way, e.g. masonry.

I am familiar with Backbone Marionette, so using that, I would probably use the `onShow` method. With Angular2, what can I do to check that the DOM is fully rendered so I can call the next JS methods?

Code snippet:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'my-views',
  templateUrl: 'app/views/views.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['app/views/views.component.css'],
  directives: [HeaderComponent]
})

export class ViewsComponent implements OnInit {
  ...

  ngOnInit() {
    this.user = new User();

    if (this.user.session_id) {
      this.getList();
    } else {
      this.router.navigate(['login']);
    }
  }

  ngAfterViewInit() {
    var elem = document.querySelector('.grid');
    var colWidth = document.querySelector('.grid-size');

    var msnry = new Masonry(elem, {
      // options
      itemSelector: '.grid-item',
      columnWidth: colWidth,
      percentPosition: true
    });
  }

  getList() {
    this.getList(this.user)
      .then(Array => {
        this.myViews = Array;
      });
  }

}
```

I put a breakpoint inside the `ngAfterViewInit` hook and when it was hit, the DOM isn't showing the list yet. I know that the code I have inside the hook works because when I run the same snippet in the console after the list has been successfully rendered, it ran successfully.

Comment: did you implement OnInit interface on your component class?

Comment: This part? `export class ViewsComponent implements OnInit {`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try one of the below lifecycle hooks :

```
export class demoComponent{
    //called fter initializing the component's views and child views 
    ngAfterViewInit(){
    }
    //after every check of the component's views and child views
    ngAfterContentInit(){
    }
    //after projecting content into the component.
    ngAfterViewChecked(){
    }
}
```

Comment: I tried all those before too but none of them worked - I updated my question with code snippet.

Comment: I moved some code around and then tried `ngAfterViewChecked()` and it worked!

Answer (score 1):

There are several lifecycle hooks in Angular2: https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/lifecycle-hooks.html

I think you're going to want to use: AfterViewInit

Comment: I tried using ngAfterViewInit before too but that didn't worked - I updated my question with code snippet.